# I am not able to read from the file

Tags: c++, oop, file-handling

my question is whenever i try to read from the file both name and roll number,it only read roll number from file,please help me to sort out the problem. i have given my code below.the problem only occurs when i try to write file from one class and read from another.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    string name;
    int rollno;
public:
    void setdata();
    void display();
    void Check();
};

void A::setdata()
{
    cout<<"enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"enter rollno"<<endl;
    cin>>rollno;

}

void A::display()
{
    cout<<name<<"    "<<rollno<<endl;
}

void A::Check()
{
    A a;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("aa.txt",ios::in);
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file.read((char*)&a,sizeof(a));
        a.display();
    }
}

class B
{
public:
    void enter();

};

void B::enter()
{
    A a;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("aa.txt",ios::out);
    a.setdata();
    file.write((char*)&a,sizeof(a));
}

int main()
{
    A a1;
    B b1;
    b1.enter();
    a1.Check();
}
```

Comment: Start by realizing you cannot binary-read and/or write a `std::string` member in the manner you're using. `class A` isn't a POD (plain old data) type. By laying down content on top of the `name` member you're invoking *undefined behavior*. And your question should include a usable sample of the source input file that is griefing you.

Comment: Memory for the string value is usually allocated on the heap - std:string is not POD.

Comment: I don't see any file close after you're done writing or reading it.

Comment: @a4anurag `fstream` objects are closed in destructor, so in that sense code is fine

Comment: he should be writing individual fields of the class one by one rather than treating the whole object as a single chunk of memory and treating it as if its a char* c type string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read/write any object in c++ just by using it as a memory blob. That would only work for POD and only if that POD does not have any pointers. You have to implement read/write field by field and in case of `int` you can use method you chosen, but not for `std::string`. For example you may store data size marker for string and then actual data, or you can store zero padded fixed memory block - that's up to you.
For example (error handling is omitted):

```
void A::store( std::ostream &out )
{
    int len = name.length();
    out.write( (const char *)&len, sizeof( len ) );
    out.write( name.c_str(), len );
    out.write( (const char *)&rollno, sizeof( rollno ) );
}

void A::load( std::istream &in )
{
    int len = 0;
    in.read( (char *)&len, sizeof( len ) );
    name.resize( len );
    std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<char>( in ), len, name.begin() );
    in.read( (char *)&rollno, sizeof( rollno ) );
}

void B::enter()
{
    A a;
    a.setdata();
    ofstream file("aa.txt",ios::out);
    a.store( file );
}
```

Comment: "out.write( name.c_str(), len );" what this statement will do and why you are writing the length to the file.

Comment: @jawad when you read data for a string you need to know how many symbols to read. One of the ways is to store size first, which by itself is fixed size like `int`. Or you can store `\0` as delimiter and read byte by byte till that delimiter. You just need to be consistent in read and write accordingly.

Comment: @jawad that statement writes content of the string into file. `std::string::c_str()` returns `const char *` that can be used by c functions as c strings.

Comment: thanks a lot foe helping me now i understand where was the problem